# How can I add private events in SharePoint Calendar

Tags: calendar

I am developing a SharePoint site. How can I make users to create an event in the SharePoint Calendar and others can not see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Calendar list settings.
Edit the default view and set the Filter for view as below.

[image: filter view]